# Packaging and installing media items not working - items are created but have no attached file, media is NOT stored in file system

Tags: media-library, packages

I've created a package of media items on my prod environment and installed it on my local. The media files are NOT stored in the file system

[image]

But when I install the package, the items are created but no media is attached

[image]

EDIT: I get this error on installation. It's occurring on `packageinstall:items:ended` so I'm not sure if it's related:

```
ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'packageinstall:items:ended' event.
Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException 
Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Source[1]: Sitecore.ContentSearch 
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, Boolean checkLocation)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.GetContextIndexRanking(IIndexable indexable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Min(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.IContextIndexRankable.GetContextIndexRanking(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex.c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0(ISearchIndex i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex.GetContextIndex(IIndexable indexable, GetContextIndexArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.FetchIndex.Process(GetContextIndexArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.GetContextIndex.GetContextIndexPipeline.Run(ICorePipeline pipeline, GetContextIndexArgs args)
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3.GetEnumerator()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Events.PackagingEventHandler.HandleInstalledItems(List`1 installedItems)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
```

Comment: I have a hunch but not enough of a hunch to actually give it as an answer yet. But what happens if you install the package twice?  Yes, exact same operation again. Just the installation, no need to create the package again.

Comment: I've tried running the installation multiple times

Comment: Any error in the logs while the package installs?

Comment: Yes, I do have errors. It's occurring on package:install:end so I didn't think it would be related, but I've added it to the body

Comment: What about the mime/type. Are you using default ones?

Comment: yeah it's just image/jpeg

Comment: try to comment Sitecore.ContentSearch.Events.PackagingEventHandler, Sitecore.ContentSearch, and then install package and see if you can see changes

Comment: What is your package size? Any errors on the server where the package was generated? Have you tried to install that package into a different Sitecore instance? (e.g into a clean instance? )

Comment: Did you try the suggestion from @GauravAgarwal?